# Items moving in on page scroll bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, parallax

I used to have a page working but now it seems that it stopped. I had DIVs coming in on page scroll. my code looks like this:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($(".MY_DIV").offset().top -$(window).height())) {
    var offset = Math.min(0, $(window).scrollTop(); - ($(".MY_DIV").offset().top + $(window).height() - (($(window).height()/2) * 3)));
    $('.MY_DIV').css({
    'animation': 'fadein 2s',
    'transform' : 'translate('+offset / -15+'%, 0px)',
    'visibility':'visible'
})
```

This is all inside $(window).scroll function. It seems that offset is always 0 I can not seem to find out why though and the strange thing is that is worked when developer made it at first. Your help would mean world, thanks.